# Have problems select document and apply filter on it's subco

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So here is the deal, I am using Mongoose and I have a PollOptionSchema which has a list of voters

```
let PollOptionSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    voters: [{ user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, time: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }]
});
```

One of the document in Database is something like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56a8365fa619b9466d422ef7"
    },
    "name": "more",
    "voters": [
        {
            "user": {
                "$oid": "56a98ab1bc6279200c39c276"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "56a98ac0bc6279200c39c277"
            },
            "time": {
                "$date": "2016-01-28T03:28:00.090Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "$oid": "56b0487a9f10c4e3d1012aff"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "56b04e0fd889825ad7932336"
            },
            "time": {
                "$date": "2016-02-02T06:34:55.254Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 2
}
```

What I want to get is this PollOption Documents with only the user whose id equals a query parameter. In other word, if $userid = "56b0487a9f10c4e3d1012aff", I want to get the document below. Typically only one element in "voters" will return.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56a8365fa619b9466d422ef7"
    },
    "name": "more",
    "voters": [
        {
            "user": {
                "$oid": "56b0487a9f10c4e3d1012aff"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "56b04e0fd889825ad7932336"
            },
            "time": {
                "$date": "2016-02-02T06:34:55.254Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 2
}
```

I have tried the code below ($userId is a parameter from client)

```
optionModel.findById(optionId)
            .elemMatch('voters.user', { _id: { $eq: $userId } })
            .exec()
```

but the query above just returned null. I have searched the web for a long time but couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have about three ways of going about this, all of which use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** to return the desired result. With the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method you can use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator to return the `voters` array with only the elements that match the filter condition, this is available with MongoDB version 3.2. How do you go about this then?
Well, the following example demonstrates this:

```
// Define the pipeline
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "voters.user": userId }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            // Use the $filter on the voters array
            "voters": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$voters",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$el.user", userid  ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

// Run the aggregation pipeline
optionModel.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
    if(err) { /* Handle error */ }
    console.log(result);
});
```

Or run the aggregation using the fluent API on the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** method:

```
optionModel.aggregate()
          .match({ "$match": { "voters.user": userId } })
          .project({
               "name": 1,
               // Use the $filter on the voters array
               "voters": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$voters",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$el.user", userid  ]
                    }
               }
            }
         })
         .exec(function (err, result){
             if(err) { /* Handle error */ }
             console.log(result);
         });
```

For MongoDB versions < 3.2, the other alternatives would be to use a combination of the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** and **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** to filter contents from the arrays as follows:

```
// Define the pipeline
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "voters.user": userId }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            // Use $map and $setDifference on the voters array
            "votes": { 
                "$setDifference": [
                    { 
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$votes",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": { 
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$el.user", userId ] },
                                    "$$el",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
];
```

or the lesser performant query invloving **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**:

```
// Define the pipeline
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "votes.user": userId }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$votes" },
    {
        "$match": { "votes.user": userId }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "votes": { "$push": "$votes" },
            "name": { "$first": "$name" }
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Aggregate function does the job. Thanks a lot

Comment: @YongWang No worries, happy to help :) By the way, which operators did you apply to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I used the first and second solutions. Unwind is a bit tricky. By the way, the second solution is really smart :)